# Google Sheets import

Tags: google-apps-script, import, google-sheets

Since the importrange formula does not cope, I use this script, but it completely depends on the number of lines in the primary document (that is, I cannot do the import until my number of lines matches). The file from which the data is taken is dynamic and the lines change, each time you have to manually change the number of lines. Tell me how to import data, regardless of the number of rows? And how to import not only in cell A1? And for example in cell B2?

```
 // source document
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sId');
 // source sheet
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('name'); 
 // Get data range
 var SRange = ss.getRange("A:H"); 
 // Copy to cell. In this case (A1)
 var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
 // get data values in range
 var SData = SRange.getValues();
 // Target table. Where to unload
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('tid'); 
 // Destination sheet. Where to import
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('name');
 // Clear the range before copying.
   ts.getRange("A:H").clearContent();
 // Copy to cell. In this case (A1)
   ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

Comment: Hi, only questions in english are allowed, you should try to translate to english.

Comment: Hoh,sorry...done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function copyMyData(sid,tid,sname,tname,row,col,rows,cols) {
  var sid=sid || 'default-sid';
  var tid=tid || 'default-tid';
  var sname=sname || 'Sheet1';
  var tname=tname || 'Sheet2';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sid);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sname);
  var row=row || 1;
  var col=col || 1;
  var rows=rows || sh.getLastRow()-row+1;
  var cols=cols || sh.getLastColumn()-col+1;
  if(sid && tid && sname && tname && row && col && rows && cols) {
    var rg=sh.getRange(row,col,rows,cols); 
    var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(tid); 
    var tsh=tss.getSheetByName(tname);
    //tsh.getRange(rg.getA1Notation()).clearContent();
    tsh.clearContents();//you might want to clear the entire sheet
    tsh.getRange(rg.getA1Notation()).setValues(rg.getValues());
  }
}
```

I used this to test it a little.

```
function tstCopyMyData() {
  copyMyData(null,null,null,null,5,3,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Thak you very much. It is that me need :) :) You saved me))))))Thank you so much )